# how to get Postgres error displays using psql text mode?

Tags: postgresql, psql

Verbose works in binary mode

```
pg_restore --host=localhost --create --clean  --verbose --password --disable-triggers --username=postgres -d pg_for_es3 C:\alex\w2p_stor\pg_alex_binary_backup_20160710.sql
```

How to get it to work in text mode? (Can you please type out the whole complete line using below example so I can understand?)

```
psql -f C:\alex\w2p_stor\pg_alex_text_backup_20160710.sql --host=localhost --password --username=postgres  -d pg_for_es3
```

Am running Postgres on Windows.

Comment: the `psql` line looks ok. what error you get?..

Comment: sorry, no errors raised on the 2nd line I typed, but no error reports are displayed like in the top line. 

When I try adding error reporting (e.g., --verbose), that is not accepted

Comment: any one know how to get the diagnostics to appear?

Comment: please add scriinshot of what you see running `psql`?..

Comment: it just runs normally with no erros, data/schema are successfully updated but no diagnostics appears.  Screen shot looks like this:

ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
ALTER TABLE
REVOKE
REVOKE
GRANT
GRANT

Comment: and what verbosity do you expect?.. give screenshot of pg_restore

Comment: with binary version, I get the error count at the bottom:

pg_restore: setting owner and privileges for FK CONSTRAINT "public.wholeorpart_m
odified_by_fkey"
pg_restore: setting owner and privileges for FK CONSTRAINT "public.yorn_created_
by_fkey"
pg_restore: setting owner and privileges for FK CONSTRAINT "public.yorn_modified
_by_fkey"

 **WARNING: errors ignored on restore: 1295 **

Comment: a wild guess - add ` --set ON_ERROR_STOP=1` to your `psql` line, so it would be `psql -f C:\alex\w2p_stor\pg_alex_text_backup_20160710.sql --host=localhost --password --username=postgres  -d pg_for_es3  --set ON_ERROR_STOP=1`